# Structure map calling dispose multiple times when using nested container

Tags: structuremap

Dispose on object instances getting called twice when disposing the nested container at the end of the httprequest. However, controller dispose called once correctly. Below is detailed info on issue. Kindly advice.

1. Running Webapi+Owin
2. Startup.cs
    var registry = new Registry();
    registry.IncludeRegistry();
    registry.IncludeRegistry();
    var container = new Container(registry);
    config.Services.Replace(typeof(IHttpControllerActivator), new  ServiceActivator(container));

3.Service Activator for WebAPI

```
public class ServiceActivator : IHttpControllerActivator
 {
     private readonly IContainer _container;
     public ServiceActivator(IContainer structureMapContainer)
     {
        _container = structureMapContainer;
     }

     public IHttpController Create(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type controllerType)
     {
        var nested = _container.GetNestedContainer();
        var instance = nested.GetInstance(controllerType) as IHttpController;
        request.RegisterForDispose(nested);
        return instance;
      }
   }
```

4 Controller Registry Convention

```
 public class ControllerConvention : IRegistrationConvention
 {
    public void Process(Type type, Registry registry)
    {
        if (type.CanBeCastTo(typeof(ApiController)) && !type.IsAbstract)
        {
            registry.For(type).LifecycleIs(new UniquePerRequestLifecycle());
        }
    }
 }
```

5.Repository Registry Convention()

```
 public class RepositoryConvention : IRegistrationConvention
 {
    public void Process(Type type, Registry registry)
    {
        if (!type.IsAbstract)
        {
            registry.For(type).LifecycleIs(new UniquePerRequestLifecycle());
        }
    }
}
```

6. RepositoryRegistry

```
public class RepositoryRegistry : Registry
   {
    public RepositoryRegistry()
    {
        Scan(scan =>
        {
           scan.TheCallingAssembly();


           //DISPOSE ON EventStoreHandler GETTING CALLED TWICE AT THE END OF  THE REQUEST
           For<IEventStoreHandler>().Add<EventStoreHandler>().Named("Default");
           For<IEventStoreHandler>().Add<EventStoreHandlerB>().Named("CustomerB");

 //scan.WithDefaultConventions();  //DISPOSE ON EventStoreHandler GETTING  CALLED ONCE  AS EXPECTED AT THE END OF THE REQUEST
           For<IEventStoreHandler>().Use("Default"); //Default

            scan.With(new RepositoryConvention());
        });
    }
  }
```

If I use the scan.WithDefaultConventions(), EventStoreHandler Dispose is called once (as expected). However, I do not want to use the WithDefaultConventions. Using anything else calls the dispose twice.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
For<IEventStoreHandler>().Add<EventStoreHandlerB>().Named("CustomerB");
For<IEventStoreHandler>().Add<EventStoreHandler>().Named("Default");  

//This line fixed it       
For<IEventStoreHandler>().Use<EventStoreHandler>().Ctor<IEventStoreHandler>().Is(i => i.GetInstance<IEventStoreHandler>("Default"));
```